# getting value of typeahead textfield while typing

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I am using twitter's `typeahead`. I added a `keyup` listener:

```
myTypeAhead.on('keyup', function(evt) {
  if (event.keyCode == 27 || event.keyCode == 13 || $searchOnKeyUp) {
    console.log('causing blur: '+ $$(this).value)
    myTypeAhead.blur();
  }
})
```

During on `blur`, I tried to read the text field value, but despite it being shown in the browser (chrome in my case), `textfield.value` returns an empty string. I have tried various things, but they have all failed.

Once I leave the text field and put my focus elsewhere, `textfield.value` works fine and returns the correct value. What is wrong?